# Different dlls in Entity Framework Code First Migrations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-migrations

I have a MVC 4 Project (Company.Project.WebUI), a project for all my model classes (Company.Project.Data) and a project for the DAL (Company.Project.Services).

How can I manage this with Code First Migrations?

I'm getting the following error when I write the command `Add-Migration Init`:

`

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.FindConfiguration()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.GetMigrator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.GetPendingMigrationsRunner.RunCore()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
```

`

When I write the command `Add-Migration -StartUpProjectName "Company.Project.Services" Init` I'll get also an error

`

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Company.Project.WebUI' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Company.Project.WebUI'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.FindConfiguration()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.GetMigrator()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.GetPendingMigrationsRunner.RunCore()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
```

`

Could somebody tell me what's the best way to use EF Code First Migration with different dlls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but EF wants your DAL project to be set as the start up project in Visual Studio. I just had the same error and this solved the problem.

On Solution Explorer: Right Click to your DAL project -> select "Set as StartUp Project".